# iOS saving arrays of UIViews to file then reloading

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray, save

I am having trouble saving data when my app is terminated.

Currently i have an mutable array of strings that are loaded in a uicollection view when the app loads this array saves and loads fine.

I then have an mutable array of mutable arrays of UIViews.

(FIRST Mutable ARRAY --> Second Mutable Array 1, Second Array 2 etc --> UIView 1, UIView 2 etc)

This is what will not save.

Is it possible to save Mutable arrays of UIViews?

Im not sure if i have worded this in the best way but i hope you understand.

I can post code if needed but i used this tutorial as a basis

http://mobileorchard.com/how-to-make-an-iphone-app-part-6-saving-data/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you subclassing the UIViews? `UIView` itself conforms to `NSCoding` so there should be no problem.

Comment: Any more information about what "will not save" means?  Error messages?  Empty file?  Bad content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a custom class, you need to make sure it implements the `NSCoding` protocol in order to save it to disk.

To save and load it you need to use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

```
// SAVE
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: myArray toFile: myFilePath]

// LOAD
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile: myFilePath];
```

The regular `writeToFile:atomically:` and `writeToURL:atomically:` methods only allow you to write property list objects. They fail if there are any non-property list objects in the array. Property list objects are: `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`, `NSData`, `NSDate`, and `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help. This worked straight away and solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no difference in an `NSArray` of `UIViews` versus an `NSArray` of `NSStrings`.  They are both Obj-C objects and other than performance (footprint of an `NSString` is very small compared to a `UIView` that may contain other objects), the `NSArray` will behave the same in both cases.

You will need to post code if you want further help.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but have you allocated the `NSMutableArray`?

I've forgotten that a couple of times and it's a easy one to forget.